# Read .csv to a multidimensional array, then pass it to JavaScript

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a .CSV file, generated by the user in Microsoft Excel, that needs to be turned into a web form.

```
id,partial-allowed,amount,description,contents,price
0,TRUE,88 count,California Fancy Navels,,27
1,TRUE,48 count,Texas Rio Star Red Grapefruit,,22
2,TRUE,100 count,Washington Red Delicious Apples,,40
3,TRUE,100 count,Washington Golden Delicious Apples,,40
4,TRUE,100 count,Braeburns,,40
5,FALSE,40 count,Apple Sampler,"8 Red Delicious, 8 Golden Delicious, 8 Granny Smith, 8 Fuji, 8 Braeburn",22
6,FALSE,20 count,Apple Sampler,"4 Red Delicious, 4 Golden Delicious, 4 Granny Smith, 4 Fuji, 4 Braeburn",16
7,FALSE,18 pound,Number 1 Mixed Fruit Box,"18 Navel Oranges, 8 Red Delicious Apples, 10 Braeburn Apples",20
8,FALSE,18 pound,Number 2 Mixed Fruit Box,"14 Navel Oranges, 6 Red Delicious & 6 Braeburns Apples, 10 D’Anjou Pears",20
9,FALSE,18 pound,Number 3 Mixed Fruit Box,"8 Grapefruit, 12 Navel Oranges, 10 Braeburn Apples",20
10,FALSE,18 pound,Number 4 Mixed Fruit Box,"6 Grapefruit, 12 Navel Oranges, 4 Red Delicious & 4 Braeburn Apples 6 D’Anjou Pears",20
11,FALSE,18 pound,Number 5 Mixed Fruit Box,11 Grapefruit and 18 Oranges,20
```

I managed to successfully import this into PHP and use it to generate the form properly, but now it won't pass into JSON properly.

```
<?php
$csvHandle = fopen('Sale Data/Fruit-Sale.2013.csv', 'r');

$partialCase = array();
$completeCase = array();

//used to skip the header row
$keys = fgetcsv($csvHandle, 0, ',');

while(($data = fgetcsv($csvHandle, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) {
    $item = array(
        //changes the string value to a numeric value
        'id' => intval($data[0]),
        //changes the string value to a boolean value
        'partial-allowed' => filter_Var($data[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
        'amount' => $data[2],
        'description' => $data[3],
        'contents' => $data[4],
        //changes the string value to a numeric value
        'price' => intval($data[5])
        );
    $item['partial-allowed'] == true ?
        array_push($partialCase, $item) : array_push($completeCase, $item);
}
echo "\npartialCase\n";
//outputs properly as an array, or an object if I pass the constant JSON_FORCE_OBJECT
echo json_encode($partialCase);
echo "\ncompleteCase\n";
//outputs nothing
echo json_encode($completeCase);
?>
```

Originally it was taken from the CSV as a single array and then was split into the two arrays, but I found that was unnecessary and took it out [it didn't work then either]. I'm at the point of tearing out hair wondering why one array is passed properly while the other is not.

Below is the output, I also couldn't figure out why it wasn't splitting into multiple lines. EDIT: This was corrected, thanks to @Duotrigesimal

```
partialCase[{"id":0,"partial-allowed":true,"amount":"88 count","description":"California Fancy Navels","contents":"","price":27},{"id":1,"partial-allowed":true,"amount":"48 count","description":"Texas Rio Star Red Grapefruit","contents":"","price":22},{"id":2,"partial-allowed":true,"amount":"100 count","description":"Washington Red Delicious Apples","contents":"","price":40},{"id":3,"partial-allowed":true,"amount":"100 count","description":"Washington Golden Delicious Apples","contents":"","price":40},{"id":4,"partial-allowed":true,"amount":"100 count","description":"Braeburns","contents":"","price":40}]completeCase
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the ternary statement like that. Ternary is good for conditional assignment but not for control structure.

Comment: @Phil noted, and changed.

Comment: Did it work? I did some tests and I think the ternary may work, ugly as it is

Comment: Yes, using the ternary had the same behavior as switching it to if/else. The array is still not passed into JSON properly.

Comment: How about omitting the optional arguments to `fgetcsv`? Simply try `fgetcsv($csvHandle)`

Comment: @Phil that didn't change anything, still got the same output.

Comment: Your code works fine for me using a local test. Are you completely sure your `Sale Data/Fruit-Sale.2013.csv` file contains the data you expect? Perhaps try dumping its contents with `readfile('Sale Data/Fruit-Sale.2013.csv')`

Comment: I just did that, and it outputted exactly what is in the file. Someone else I asked also had it output the JSON correctly as-is. I discovered that if I omit the "contents" key from the array, my JSON encodes properly. Unfortunately, I can't just ditch part of my data, so I need that. I also made sure that PHP has the arrays stored properly using `print_r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem after a lot of tinkering.
This line:

```
'contents' => $data[4],
```

Needed the ampersand and commas escaped, like so:

```
'contents' => htmlentities($data[4], ENT_NOQUOTES)
```

And because `"’"` has no escape character, it needed to be changed to `"'"` in the CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back when you solved the problem! People don't do this enough.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the last part of your question. Getting the json to output to multiple lines is done by passing the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` constant to `json_encode`. This is available if you're using php 5.4+.

```
echo json_encode($partialCase, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: I meant why the PHP wasn't outputting it to multiple lines on the page, in my dump of the data to see what was wrong. It's just ignoring the newline sequences. Passing this also didn't output it to multiple lines.

Comment: Oh, that's because HTML ignores the `\n` character most of the time. Either us `<br>`, or put a `<pre>` tag before your output.